# Empty intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$x\in \bigcap \emptyset \iff (\forall b \in \emptyset)\,x\in b$$
Can it be drawn that $\forall x,\,x\in \bigcap \emptyset$ using the right hand side of above? How to show $(\forall b \in \emptyset)\,k\in b$ for an arbitrary element $k$?

Comment: Can you any $b$ with $b\in\varnothing$ and $k\notin b$?

Comment: @drhab I read some posts in this MSE. Most of them use your approach. Assume $k \not\in b$ then it leads contradiction. That makes sense but I want to start at the definition and prove it directly. Is it possible?

Comment: Op ol, have you seen the duplicate? Your question is answered there

Comment: I think it is a matter of accepting the Boolean concept: if a statement is false then its negation is true (tertium non datur).